# logits and labels must have the same first dimension CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a simple CNN model, here's the structure

image's size is 64X64

**1st layer: convolution 5X5X8 average pooling 5X5 strides 2**

**2nd layer: convolution 5X5X8 average pooling 5X5 strides 2**

**3rd layer: convolution 1X1X32 average pooling global pooling**

**4th layer: fully connected layer 32inputs 2outputs**

when I use sparse_softmax_cross_entropy to calculate the loss, it raise an Error like this:

[image]

I thought the shape of Tensor output by 4th layer should be (?, 2) and it is, but I dont understand why the shape of logits is [**1280**, 2]

```
def stg_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    # Input Layer
    x = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 64, 64, 1])
    # print(x)
    x = layer_module.conv_group(
        inputs = x,
        activation = "tanh",
        filters = 8,
        kernel_size = [5, 5],
        pool_size = 5,
        strides = 2,
        abs_layer = True,
        pool_padding = "same")
    print(x)

    x = layer_module.conv_group(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 16,
        activation = "tanh",
        kernel_size = [5, 5],
        pool_size = 5,
        strides = 2,
        abs_layer = False,
        pool_padding = "same")
    print(x)

    x = layer_module.conv_group(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 32,
        activation = "relu",
        kernel_size = [1, 1],
        pool_size = 16,
        strides = 1,
        abs_layer = False,
        pool_padding = "valid")
    print(x)


    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32])
    x = tf.layers.dense(inputs = x, units = 2)




    predictions = {
        # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=x, axis=1),
        # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
        # `logging_hook`.
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(x, name="softmax_tensor")
        }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
        # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = labels, logits = x)



if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=FLAGS.learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)
    # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Comment: Because `?` means as many as the batch size and your batch size seems to be 1280.

Comment: @Pop I set the batch_size to 20, and the shape of sparse labels is [20] which means the batch size is actually 20. so i got confused

Comment: Ok. Then, you should check the dimension of your data at each step (i.e. after each convolutional and pooling layer) of you model to find where it goes wrong

Comment: the shape of the 4th layer output is correct (?, 2), dont know why it would change after I pass the output into sparse_softmax_cross_entropy.But thanks for your answer.@Pop

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you messed up the computation of dimensions.
Just before the output you do `x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32])`. At this point you assume that x has a shape of `(?, 1, 1, 32)`. Since you are not getting (batch size, 32) back I expect that is not the case.

Double check that the x before the reshape has the right shape and adjust accordingly.

Comment: the output of the 3rd layer is (?, 1, 1, 32).So I do the reshape to make it shape like (?, 32). Will it be the problem? @Sorin